# Examples of problems that are easier by knowing eigenvalues/vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, problem-solving, eigenfunctions

I've recently started studying some of perturbation theory and I've noted that there are several operators that doesn't have any eigenvalue in their spectrum, but by adding little perturbations you can add even countable of them. The analysis is interesting by itself, I would like to know more about applications though. I know that somewhere there have to be plenty of them.

I've actually seen some examples in my PDE course, for example the Laplace's problem on certain domains is transformed into a fourier series problem by just knowing the eigenvalues/vectors, and the same happen when you take the heat equation on bounded domains.

So the question is: Do you know any other examples of problems with operators that are easier to solve by knowing their eigenvalues/vectors? I hope the question is not too open.

Comment: I must have missed the point of your question because _all_ problems are easier to solve by knowing their eigenvalues and eigenvectors. If you know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then you've already solved the problem...

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained it accurately. What I want to know is $\textit{problems}$ that are easier to solve by using eigenvalues/vectors methods. Problems that I'm looking for are $\textit{not}$ about finding eigenvalues/vectors, instead I'm looking for problems that a $\textit{priori}$ doesn't even have something to do with spectrum properties.

Comment: What do you mean by 'eigenvalues/vectors' method? I've never heard of it.

Comment: Any method that use eigen stuff.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. As it stands, isn't clear. You might want to update your post, maybe including an example, to help explain what you mean.

Comment: What is not clear? There are actually two examples, not well explained I know, but certainly every person that have taken a ODE course with some level of mathematical accuracy would get what I mean.